# Efficient algorithm for Virtual Machine(VM) Consolidation in Cloud

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cloud, scheduling, bin-packing

***PROBLEM:*** 
We have **N** physical machines(PMs) each with ram **R**<sub>i</sub>, cpu **C**<sub>i</sub> and a set of currently scheduled VMs each with ram  requirement **r**<sub>i</sub> and **c**<sub>i</sub> respectively 
Moving(Migrating) any VM from one PM to other has a cost associated which depends on its ram **r**<sub>i</sub>. A PM with no VMs is shut down to save power.
 
Our target is to minimize the weighted sum of (N,migration cost) by migrating some VMs i.e. minimize the number of working PMs as well as not to degrade the service level due to excessive migrations.

***My Approach:***
Brute Force approach is choosing the minimum loaded PM and try to fit its VMs to other PMs by first Fit decreasing algorithm or we can select the victim PMs and target PMs based on their loading level and shut down victims if possible by moving their VMs to targets. 
I tried this Greedy approach on the Data of *Baadal*(IIT-D cloud) but It isn't giving promising results.

I have also tried to study the Ant colony optimization for dynamic VM consolidating but was unable to understand very much. I used the links.
http://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/docs/00/72/52/15/PDF/Esnault.pdf
http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/72/38/56/PDF/RR-8032.pdf

Would anyone please clarify the solution or suggest any new approach/resources for better 
performance.
I am basically searching for the algorithms not the physical optimizations and I also know that many commercial organizations have provided these solution but I just wanted to know more the underlying algorithms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/241536/34181, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23961204/781723.  Please don't cross-post -- it violates SE rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a shareing-aware algorithm for virtual machine colocation. Here is a paper:http://www.australianscience.com.au/research/google/37147.pdf.